# NSCalendar [_NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper component:fromDate:]: error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscalendar, cal

In a tableviewcontroller I have this code to get an array of days from 0 to 6 where it is order with the current dayNumber first.

```
self.dayOrder=[NSMutableArray new];

NSCalendar *cal=[NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSInteger dayNumber = [cal component:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]]-1; // Sunday gives 0,

for (int i=0;i<7;i++) {
    [self.dayOrder addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:dayNumber]];
    dayNumber=(dayNumber+1)%7;
}
```

When I move to this view controller I get this error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper component:fromDate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15e4b850'`

And when I add an ALL Exceptions break point the error is occuring at this line

```
 NSInteger dayNumber = [cal component:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]]-1; // Sunday gives 0,
```

It seems to be working on my iPhone 6 but which is on iOS 8 but not iPone 4,5c which are on iOS7.

Not sure why this is happening, any help of why it is would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `component:fromDate:` method was added to `NSCalendar` in iOS 8.0.

If you need to support older iOS versions, then use the older `components:fromDate:` method and extract the value you need from the resulting `NSDateComponents`.

```
NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSInteger weekday = [components weekday] - 1;
```

Comment: okay so I have this `    NSDateComponents *day = [cal components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:[NSDate date]];
` and then how do I get that into integer